# GCM account expires

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a small application using GCM Service.

Before, I tried to send to my self a message, but (server side) the answer has been:

> "success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}

But at the beggining of my app i check this:

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);  if (regId.equals("")) 
        {
                //  Register
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);


        } 
        else ...
```

It seems evident that getRegistrationId() works fine only locally, (SharedPreferences ?)..

The nice thing is that i never did Unregister my app,just reinstall it, not changing version number (because it is in test,still) so in this case my account has expired, in those cases google should not send me another id that i could catch here:

```
@Override
    protected void onRegistered
```

???

However there is a safe way to understand if my app is registered GCM server side?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

I'm thinking this:

When i reinstall my application through Eclipse, there is a moment where my application is not installed, if GCM server send me a message in that moment there is no receiver and so google unvalidates my ID.
In your opinion is this idea, a stupid idea?

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html.

It could happen because some time gcm registartion id gets expired so everytime you should check that is it registered or not if not register it

Comment: Thanks for answer, in that example application save REGID in sharedPreferences and at the start check if regid has been previously saved. I think that getRegistratiodId() make same thing, but if an user received something by that function, he cannot be sure to be truely registered GCM SERVER SIDE.

Answer (score 0):

You should only register the device one time. Save the registrationId in some way (shared preferences is a good one) and use it.

From the documentation:

> Register the application for GCM and return the registration ID. **You must call this once**, when your application is installed, and send the returned registration ID to the server.

In some tests i've made, the registration id returned by `gcm.register(id)` isn't always the same for the device,app pair. However, Google says:

> Repeated calls to this method will return the original registration ID.

If the method `gcm.register(id)` returns an id, it will be valid ever since.

Best.

Comment: Of course i call register just one time.
My main problem is that getRegistrationId() returns an id not empty but that is not registered on GCM server side, but i'm not sure why, however i would like to know a method to check if an ID is GCM registered.

Comment: If the GCM server returns an ID to you, you can only expect Google to keep it registered on its servers. I don't think an registration id will ever be expired on GCM server.

However, if you're not sure your user is registered, just register again in GCM server, and send the registration ID to the 3rd party server.